# Approximate the proportion of integers with neighboring factors

Tags: code-golf, number

If 1 is not counted as a factor, then

- 40 has two neighboring factors (4 and 5)
- 1092 has two neighboring factors (13 and 14)
- 350 does not have two neighboring factors
  (out of its factors 2, 5, 7, 10, 14, 25, 35, 50, 70, and 175,
  no two are consecutive)

The proportion of positive integers that have this property
is the proportion divisible by any of
6 (2 × 3), 12 (3 × 4), 20 (4 × 5), 30, 56, ….
If we only calculate the proportion divisible by the first *n* of these,
we get an approximation that gets more accurate as *n* increases.

For example,
for *n=1*,
we find the proportion of integers divisible by 2 × 3 = 6,
which is 1/6.
For *n=2*,
all integers divisible by 3 × 4 = 12 are also divisible by 6,
so the approximation is still 1/6.
For *n=3*,
the proportion of integers divisible by 6 or 20 is 1/5,
and so on.

Here are the first few values:

```
1  1/6                0.16666666666666666
3  1/5                0.20000000000000000
6  22/105             0.20952380952380953
9  491/2310           0.21255411255411255
12 2153/10010         0.21508491508491510
15 36887/170170       0.21676558735382265
21 65563/301070       0.21776663234463747
24 853883/3913910     0.21816623274423785
27 24796879/113503390 0.21846817967287144
```

For values of *n* between the provided values,
the output should be the same as the output for the value above
(e.g. *n=5* → 1/5).

Your program should take *n* and output either a fraction or decimal answer.
You may take *n* at any offset
(e.g. 0-indexing or 2-indexing into this sequence, instead of 1-indexing).

For decimal output,
your program must be accurate to at least 5 digits
for all the test cases given.

Scoring is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), with the shortest code winning.

<sup>Inspired by [What proportion of positive integers have two factors that differ by 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3038712/65867) by [marty cohen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13079/marty-cohen) -- specifically, by [Dan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1374/dan)'s answer.</sup>

Comment: How accurate does a decimal answer have to be? A natural strategy seems to be to count the integers with a valid divisor in some enormous range and divide by the length of the range, which gets better as an approximation as the range gets bigger.

Comment: @xnor I've now addressed that in the post.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>14 13</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 using Erik the Outgolfer's idea to take the mean of a list of zeros and ones.
-3 by using 3-indexing (as allowed in the question) - thanks to Dennis for pointing this out.

```
ḊPƝḍⱮ!Ẹ€Æm
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer, `n+2`, which yields a float.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4biKUMad4biN4rGuIeG6uOKCrMOGbf///zk)** (very inefficient since it tests divisibility over the range \$[2, (n+2)!]\$)

(Started out as `+2µḊPƝḍⱮ!§T,$Ẉ`, taking `n` and yielding `[numerator, denominator]`, unreduced)

#### How?

```
ḊPƝḍⱮ!Ẹ€Æm - Link: integer, x=n+2
Ḋ          - dequeue (implicit range of) x  - i.e. [2,3,4,...,n+2]
  Ɲ        - apply to neighbours:
 P         -   product                             [2×3,3×4,...,(n+1)×(n+2)]
     !     - factorial of x                        x!
    Ɱ      - map across (implicit range of) x! with:
   ḍ       -   divides?                            [[2×3ḍ1,3×4ḍ1,...,(n+1)×(n+2)ḍ1],[2×3ḍ2,3×4ḍ2,...,(n+1)×(n+2)ḍ2],...,[2×3ḍ(x!),3×4ḍ(x!),...,(n+1)×(n+2)ḍ(x!)]]
       €   - for each:
      Ẹ    -   any?  (1 if divisible by any of the neighbour products else 0)
        Æm - mean
```

Comment: Hm... I suspect what makes this shorter than mine is the use of `!` instead of `æl/`... Ah, the joys of rules changing while sleeping.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer yeah, very similar methods when I look closer! can you use `P` to get down to 13?

Comment: Instead of `Ẹ€`? I'm afraid `P` is the same as `×ƒ1$`, so it won't work. (And that would be 14 anyway...) If instead of `æl/`, maybe (`P` *is* LCM*k after all).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer instead of `æl/`

Comment: Yeah, I think I can do that, and the result would theoretically be as precise as with `æl/` I guess. (Night-owl golfing does have issues...) EDIT: Yeah, although I'll have to reduce the argument over TIO to `4`... :P

Comment: No need for `+2`; the challenge allows 3-indexing.

Comment: @Dennis, oh and it always has - odd that I didn't notice since I had thought it would be nice if we could start at another n. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
Ḋ×‘$ḍẸ¥ⱮP$Æm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4biKw5figJgk4biN4bq4wqXisa5QJMOGbf///zU)

-2 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)'s suggestion to replace the LCM with the product (i.e. the LCM multiplied by an integer).

[Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) noticed I can 2-index as well.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ì©!Lε®LüP¦Öà}ÅA
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177683/52210), so also extremely slow.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//8OMwqkhTM61wq5Mw7xQwqbDlsOgfcOFQf//Ng) or [verify the first three test cases](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9vc2FiaWX/fHZ5PyIg4oaSICI/ef/DjMKpIUzOtcKuTMO8UMKmw5bDoH3DhUH/LP8xCjMKNg).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ì                 # Add 2 to the (implicit) input
                  #  i.e. 3 → 5
 ©                # Store this in the register (without popping)
  !               # Take the factorial of it
                  #  i.e. 5 → 120
   L              # Create a list in the range [1, (input+2)!]
                  #   i.e. 120 → [1,2,3,...,118,119,120]
    ε       }     #  Map over each value in this list
     ®            #  Push the input+2 from the register
      L           #  Create a list in the range [1, input+2]
                  #   i.e. 5 → [1,2,3,4,5]
       ü          #  Take each pair
                  #    i.e. [1,2,3,4,5] → [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
        P         #   And take the product of that pair
                  #    i.e. [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]] → [2,6,12,20]
         ¦        #  Then remove the first value from this product-pair list
                  #   i.e. [2,6,12,20] → [6,12,20]
          Ö       #  Check for each product-pair if it divides the current map-value
                  #  (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
                  #   i.e. [1,2,3,...,118,119,120] and [6,12,20]
                  #    → [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],...,[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
           à      #  And check if it's truthy for any by taking the maximum
                  #   i.e. [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],...,[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
                  #    → [0,0,0,...,0,0,1]
             ÅA   # After the map, take the mean (and output implicitly)
                  #  i.e. [0,0,0,...,0,0,1] → 0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>94 92</s>  90 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy + 2 more bytes from there*

Returns a decimal approximation.

```javascript
n=>(x=2,g=a=>n--?g([...a,x*++x]):[...Array(1e6)].map((_,k)=>n+=a.some(d=>k%d<1))&&n/1e6)``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpLDoIwFAD3nqILNO9JqQEF46cYF3oJQ@QFCv5oCRCDIZwdYTGLmcyLvlQn1bNsHG1SNWRy0DKEVno8lyRD7TinHG5CCOLt0rbbCPeTnauKfuCqACNRUAlw528cd1uSqE2hIJXhe54eXcTFQq@mMY6Hw83lbM1ZwNmOM9cb8TnzxuhtRrbRTGSmulDyAM1kyBKja/NR4mNyiAmsTvc4davLQKNozPXZqhR87GPE4Q8)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 131 bytes

A much longer solution that returns an exact result as a pair \$[numerator, denominator]\$.

```javascript
f=(n,a=[],p=x=1)=>n?f(n-1,[...a,q=++x*-~x],p*q/(g=(a,b)=>a?g(b%a,a):b)(p,q)):[...Array(p)].map((_,k)=>n+=a.some(d=>-~k%d<1))&&[n,p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU7JTsMwEL3zFT50mWkmLgGBRMGpOPAVltVOVrrZjoNQUJX8ekgO7/BWvTP/cpuHk/@JrSvKcawUWGKlDXnVqQRVavcV2DghLaVkalQUdZt46KbAptlCrYApm2K8ryFbMjHuMgRPDeJurnyGwH/g0cgbe4ADXebNSLFs3a2EQqXxcFkWHwniaqUteTO@64TEM4lXEm8kkqcJL@ZBVi58cf4NVqhU5M627lrKq6vhyLC42x5nfXGHIJSYLiPKsztZWIutWGMvBjWZQT@aiQedmP6IOP4D)

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYpLDoIwFAD3nqILNe9JqQEV46cYF3oJQvSFFkSwNWAMxnh2LItZzGTu9KY2a8rnyzdW6T6XvZExFJJkbHz/UEAihCDezTyvS3E72LFp6AOBjjAVD3oCXHiFbvckidY@NCgZVxO1DxCnUzMfRkhS3skQ@10ScLbgLOJsw1kQOlachS6GS8c6HYncNifKbmCYjFlmTWtrLWpbwJVg/DU/HPr4m4NB8bLnstMKVvi7IvZ/)

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##FclBDoIwEIXhvafoQpMZKTWgaEQHV3oJY0JDCyg4NWIMCeHsWBf/W3zvob@6K9731ydkZ@xU0sSUQU@xrEhTxmF4quCqlNKyXwZBf8MUamooa/xTQyM5IK0697RgPC7MMUJMeRXZLcJ/MM@nwzWSYi3FVoq9FFHsS6SIPcYb3@42U6V7n3VRAwvKROG4c61Vrasg1zAfeMS/z4cSGNXHXe69NZDgmCNOPw) should work, in *theory* for 82 bytes.

Comment: @Shaggy I don't really know what the consensus is for answers like that. While it does work _in theory_, it doesn't work in practice for any input. (I personally dislike this kind of answers. This is why I usually include a rule such as "your code should at least work up to a given limit" in my own challenges when I suspect that I'll get answers such as _"works only for n=1 on TIO"_ ... or doesn't work at all in the present case.)

Comment: Personally, I'm a big fan of the infinite time & memory consensus ;)

Comment: Oh I like it too. :) My only reservation is that I think it should be possible to test any answer for at least a couple of distinct inputs.

Comment: @Shaggy I think Arnauld means that he doesn't like it if the answer can only be tested for one input because it could as well be hardcoding (testers aren't supposed to know every programming language in the world).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υ×⁺²ι⁺³ιＩ∕ＬΦΠυ¬⌊Ｅυ﹪ιλΠυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY07DsIwEER7TuFyLZmG0FGCkJBI5IILmMTglfyJ7N1c39gpmGqk0XszO5PnZHytn5QFPOLKNHF42wxSCs3FASvxwmALaM8FTkqgVGLvQ@9SXg46YyS4mkJwww0XC08bv@Tgjp6aSue08EzAjZwSwYgRAwcYzdr1Y1t9AlTCyz3N/yf6Qa3netz8Dw) Link is to verbose version of code. Hopelessly inefficient (O(n!²)) so only works up to `n=4` on TIO. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ⊞υ×⁺²ι⁺³ι
```

Input `n` and calculate the first `n` products of neighbouring factors.

```
Ｉ∕ＬΦΠυ¬⌊Ｅυ﹪ιλΠυ
```

Take the product of all of those factors and use that to calculate the proportion of numbers having at least one of those factors.

30-byte less slow version is only O(n!) so can do up to `n=6` on TIO:

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ⊞υ⁺²ιＩ∕ＬΦΠυΣＥυ∧μ¬﹪ι×λ§υ⊖μΠυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NCsIwEITvPkWOG4gXD156EotQsCWgLxCT1QbyU5JN8e1jeqlzGphvhtGzSjoqV@s7JgZD0Ak9BkLT/FJoKv6FCTjnTJY8QxFMupLhJJjlvDvIZAPBVWWC3q7WINwxfGiGm3XUijJFUzRB4YI9iodRLdvGJRjwgk2RYGyAi2AFe1qPGVxLaQgGvxvY4/@Q57vai324qav1XI@r@wE) Link is to verbose version of code.

<s>46-byte faster version is only O(lcm(1..n+2)) so can do up to `n=10` on TIO:</s>

```
ＦＮ⊞υ×⁺²ι⁺³ι≔⁰η≔⁰ζＷ∨¬η⌈Ｅυ﹪ηκ«≦⊕η≧⁺⌈Ｅυ¬﹪ηκζ»Ｉ∕ζη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/NTsMwEITP5Cn2uJaMlMKRE4JLDmkjxAu4iVuv6p/KPwEF8eyu3SKhtnua0Wi/nR2V8KMTOued84CdPaa4TmYrPTIGQwoKE4dPMjLgoFPAJw7EOJz1c9WMvTSvIdDeYstBXbmluC9FWgJuPK5dRFV2e/FNJhnsxbHCezcl7VBxOLA68NM8lOiP0tnRSyNtlNOF/p990F7Fc6s7Zj11w720@W0GTzbimwgR32mmSeJSweWNnFdtfpz1CQ) Link is to verbose version of code.

45-byte faster version is only O(2ⁿ) so can do up to `n=13` on TIO:

```
⊞υ±¹ＦＥＮ×⁺²ι⁺³ιＦ⮌υ⊞υ±÷×ικ⌈Φ⊕ι∧λ¬∨﹪ιλ﹪κλＩΣ∕¹✂υ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY69DsIwDIR3niKjK4WhdOyEQEgdChXlBUJrwCI/VX4q3j4kFBY8@U6@7zw8hB2MkDF2wT0gcHbEu/AIZVHUq5uxDFoxQaOn4I9BXdFCwdmFFDroZHCw4YyS89mrvKdhn9wZZ7QOISTjD95ov6eZRoSFRJw9E6QVL1JBwYGkT0WNHiwq1B5HyB1bPYJMDOPhZKE1Y5AmR2WOLuqZ1W/qVWdJe9gJ56FP3G9nyVkvacD8ULlcxlhWcT3LNw) Link is to verbose version of code.

54-byte fastest version uses more efficient LCM so can do up to `n=18` on TIO:

```
⊞υ±¹ＦＥＮ×⁺²ι⁺³ιＦＥυ⟦κι⟧«Ｗ⊟κ⊞⊞Ｏκλ﹪§κ±²λ⊞υ±÷Π…κ²⊟κ»ＩΣ∕¹✂υ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU87a8MwEJ7jX6HxBMrgZAlkKsniIYkg2UIHVb7EwrJlZCkPSn@7ejKmQ284jo/vdbpRXjtlU5JxbCAKdsS7Cggl59vi5jyDgxqg6ocYjrH7Qg9csIvpcARp4wgrwQwh073ONw3705HftSX0k8DvYvFsjEUG0g3QEjJF5nUa0KvgPBDXktvB1dE6@AhVX@Mro3OrFeeZQdUW//pWfdibh6kRpCe1DrB7a4u7JmcJNgnnXFL/FNKbnjhqDHCOHczaUrCzNRqzcZlf4duUyk1aPuwv) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>69</s> <s>68</s> <s>61</s> 52 bytes

```
Count[Range[#!],b_/;Or@@(# #-#&@Range[3,#]∣b)]/#!&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7872b73zm/NK8kOigxLz01WlkxVicpXt/av8jBQUNZQVlXWc0BImOsoxz7qGNxkmasvrKi2v@Aosy8EgctN30HDSPtakMdYx0zHUsdQ6Nazf8A)

3-indexed. At first I was going to use `LCM@@` but realized that `#!` would be shorter... but now it a lot of memory for `Range[#!]`...

Managed to golf down the condition by 2 bytes, which was nice.

---

Older numerical solution (56 bytes):

```
N@Count[Range[5^8],b_/;Or@@Array[(# #-#)∣b&,#,3]]/5^8&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7872b738/BOb80ryQ6KDEvPTXaNM4iVicpXt/av8jBwbGoKLEyWkNZQVlXWfNRx@IkNR1lHePYWH2gKrX/AUWZeSUOWm76DhqG2tWGOsY6ZjqWOoZGOoamOkaGtZr/AQ)

2-indexed. More efficient when `#!>5^8` (`#>9`, assuming `#` is an integer).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(any(-~i%(j*-~j)<1for j in range(2,n+2))for i in range(10**7))/1e7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcixDkAwEADQX7lFcleEdmki/ImlQmnDkarB4tcrJm98xx2XnVWyXZ9Wsw2jAW7Oa0PDN5aPy9CL8vHUSrsH8OAYguF5QlVwroi@df/KWghNVMlJpyM4jmBRaUov)

Returns the approximate decimal to +5 digits; uses the naive brute force approach [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) suggests in comments on the question.